# Run C program from Assembly program

Tags: c, ubuntu, assembly, operating-system, bootloader

I recently began attempting to program a(very) simple OS, and used this [tutorial](http://mikeos.berlios.de/write-your-own-os.html) to create a simple bootloader in Assembly. Now, I want to run a c program from the bootloader. How would I accomplish this on Ubuntu? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to include a function written in C in your OS, or do you want to jump from your bootloader to another program? In the latter case the tutorial you linked to hints where you can find more information about that at the very bottom

Comment: Based on that tutorial, I would assume you are running in 16 bit mode still. Unless you happen to have a compiler which supports this (not very common), you will need to get into [protected mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Protected_mode) before running C programs.